# Is it possible to delete a directory in constant time?

Tags: files, performance, rm

I usually remove an entire directory at once with `rm -rf`. I noticed just now that this takes longer the larger the directory is (reckoned recursively).

Do unix-like systems expose an alternative way to delete a directory that operates in constant time? It seems it should be possible to remove a directory 'directly', without touching the contents at all, which are now inaccessible.

Is there some characteristic of file systems that forces you to recursively walk the contents of a directory in order to delete the directory itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete directory, you have to delete its content recursively. Why is it so?

Simplifying we can say that «directory» is file, which contains list of pairs . What will happens, if you just "free blocks of directory on a drive"?

Let's consider deleting of regular files. Program (like `rm`) calls `unlink()` system call. Operation System (and more specifically, file system driver) checks count of hard links (`filename` in directory in previous paragraph). If it is zero and file is not opened, it can be physically deleted. Thus, we know how to delete file.

Now let's look to directory deletion again. When you just free blocks, you don't `unlink` files in it, you don't decrement counter of hard links for any file in directory. And for any file in subdirectories, subsubdirectories, etc. What is conclusion? Exactly, we need to do `unlink` for all files in the directory that we remove, because we don't want to get unremovable garbage in File System.

Thus, you can use @SYN's solution (running `rm` in background), but there is no way to remove directory in constant time.

Comment: Well done for actually answering the question.  *"Is it possible to delete a directory in constant time?"*  No, it is not.  +1

Comment: This answer isn't terribly good. There is no technical reason why you can't remove a directory tree in `O(1)`. The "unremovable garbage" that might result from not decrementing hard link counts could be dealt with by having a background cleaner / fsck.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel, you're probably right. But with two caveats. First, user feel the "constant time", but in real it isn't so. And second, your idea may be good, but i don't know any real implementation of it.

Answer (score 1):

If the directory is mounted on its own filesystem, you may unmount it, recreate the it with `newfs`, and remount it.  That will take the same amount of time regardless of the size of the directory.

Answer (score 1):

> Do unix-like systems expose an alternative way to delete a directory that operates in constant time? It seems it should be possible to remove a directory 'directly', without touching the contents at all, which are now inaccessible.

This is a question of filesystem implementation. Now most folks working in filesystems are not worried very much about `rm -rf` performance because it simply doesn't come up in the file server and database workloads that everyone is trying to optimize.

Note that `btrfs` supports ripping out a subtree in constant time - but you have to use a `subvolume` for it in advance.

Comment: Are there restrictions on hard links crossing submodule boundaries in btrfs?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Dunno. Usually with `btrfs` what you'd do is make a copy-on-write copy anyways with `cp --reflink=always` (or `=auto`). This makes them kind of like separate files but sharing blocks when possible. I think there's even a cleaner for `btrfs` that re-shares blocks that have the same content from different files. https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Deduplication

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
rm -fr /path/to/directory &
```

This would background your command

You may list backgrounded tasks with `jobs`

A job ID would be listed. Which could be used attaching back to your process :

```
$ sleep 60 &
[1] 22316
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 60 &
$ fg %1
sleep 60
```

Having already started your `rm` command, you may also hit `Ctrl`+`Z`, which would pause your command, then type `bg` to un-pause in background.

Note the list of jobs you may control with these commands are bound to your shell - and may only be recovered from current shell.